# password check without using regex in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to validate the password without using regex
but it didn't work
what I'm trying to do is the password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one alphanumeric character.
but without using Regex

here is my code

```
    import * as React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Form() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="password"
        name="password"
        ref={register({required:true,minLength:8, maxLength:16, upperCase:'true' , lowerCase:'true' )}
      />
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="Email" ref={register} />
      <br />
     
      Birthday
      <input
        type="date"
        placeholder="birthday"
        name="birthday"
        ref={register}
      />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

I have looked at many sites but I couldn't find any solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply loop over your string and compare each character (which are numbers represented in the ASCII table). Then you can simply check the counts according to the constraints you want to set.

```js
const password="MyPA55w()rd";

let upper_count = 0;
let lower_count = 0;
let number_count = 0;
let symbol_count = 0
for(let i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
  let c = password.charAt(i);

  if( 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
    upper_count +=1;
  }else if( 'a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
    lower_count +=1;
  }else if( '0' <= c && c <= '9') {
    number_count +=1;
  } else {
    symbol_count += 1;
  }
}

console.log(`Number of capital letter: ${upper_count}`);
console.log(`Number of lower letter: ${lower_count}`);
console.log(`Number of numbers: ${number_count}`);
console.log(`Number of symbols: ${symbol_count}`);
```

PS: there are also interseting tools like Formik and Yup that allows to you to check return fields in forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot
how can i prevent the user from using his birth year in the password?

Comment: Check if `password.Includes(year)`

Answer (score 0):

this one kind of solution is for js vanilla, not for react spezified:
if you don't want to use regex (regex is really nice, you should learn regex) you can create a character map for each charset that you want to check. then iterate through your password and see if the current character is in one of these character maps. additional you can create theese character maps automatically using ascii tables/codes

Comment: thank you, but it is required to not use regex!
 can you please share an example of your solution?

Comment: no sorry, you will learn it better, when you do it by yourself